# How to stop an endless loop on model migration, 'models have changes that are not yet reflected' - makemigrations > migrate. Same message

Tags: python, django, model, migration

Showmigrations:

```
accounts
 [X] 0001_initial
admin
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_logentry_remove_auto_add
 [X] 0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices
auth

 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_auto_20190430_1129
blog
 [X] 0001_initial
contenttypes
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_remove_content_type_name
core
 (no migrations)
curate
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_item_tags
django_comments
 [X] 0001_initial
podcast
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_auto_20190430_1129
 [X] 0003_auto_20190430_1132
sessions
 [X] 0001_initial
sites
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_alter_domain_unique
taggit
 [X] 0001_initial
```

If I run migrate (just to see if it says 'no migrations to apply') I get this:

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: accounts, admin, auth, blog, contenttypes, curate, django_comments
, podcast, sessions, sites, taggit
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
  Your models have changes that are not yet reflected in a migration, and so won't be appl
ied.
  Run 'manage.py makemigrations' to make new migrations, and then re-run 'manage.py migrat
e' to apply them.
```

So I run makemigrations:

```
Migrations for 'podcast':
  podcast\migrations\0004_auto_20190430_1137.py
    - Alter field published_date on show

Showmigrations:

accounts
 [X] 0001_initial
admin
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_logentry_remove_auto_add
 [X] 0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices
auth
 [X] 0001_initial

 [X] 0002_auto_20190430_1129
blog
 [X] 0001_initial
contenttypes
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_remove_content_type_name
core
 (no migrations)
curate
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_item_tags
django_comments
 [X] 0001_initial
podcast
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_auto_20190430_1129
 [X] 0003_auto_20190430_1132
 [ ] 0004_auto_20190430_1137
sessions
 [X] 0001_initial
sites
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_alter_domain_unique
taggit
 [X] 0001_initial
```

I run migrate again:

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: accounts, admin, auth, blog, contenttypes, curate, django_comments
, podcast, sessions, sites, taggit
Running migrations:
C:\Users\phill\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init
__.py:1421: RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField Show.published_date received a naive datetime (2
019-04-30 11:32:39.288026) while time zone support is active.
  RuntimeWarning)
C:\Users\phill\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init
__.py:1421: RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField Show.published_date received a naive datetime (2
019-04-30 11:37:23.102936) while time zone support is active.
  RuntimeWarning)
  Applying podcast.0004_auto_20190430_1137... OK
```

However, if I run migrate again, I get the same message - it's a loop.

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: accounts, admin, auth, blog, contenttypes, curate, django_comments
, podcast, sessions, sites, taggit
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
  Your models have changes that are not yet reflected in a migration, and so won't be appl
ied.
  Run 'manage.py makemigrations' to make new migrations, and then re-run 'manage.py migrat
e' to apply them.

makemigrations:

Migrations for 'podcast':
  podcast\migrations\0005_auto_20190430_1139.py
    - Alter field published_date on show
```

Here's the line in the model producing the runtime error, I provided a default value because it's a new attribute on an existing model and it needed one. Python also prompted me to use this, perhaps this is the wrong approach?

```
published_date = models.DateTimeField(_('Date published'), default=datetime.datetime.today(), null=True, blank=True, help_text=_('The date the feed was published'))
```

The migration code for the looping migration is here:

```
import datetime
from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('podcast', '0003_auto_20190430_1132'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='show',
            name='published_date',
            field=models.DateTimeField(blank=True, default=datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 30, 11, 37, 23, 102936), help_text='The date the feed was published', null=True, verbose_name='Date published'),
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: Show us the model and the migration code.

Comment: After some scrolling I see the problem now. `default=datetime.datetime.today()` will create a new default on every run, the new default is pushed to the database on migrations. Try without the parentheses. There should be one final migration after the change.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the callable of `datetime.date.today`, not the result of calling it, as the default. Since the result changes every time, Django will think you've changed the default.

```
published_date = models.DateTimeField(_('Date published'), default=datetime.datetime.today, null=True, blank=True, help_text=_('The date the feed was published'))
#                                                                                         ^ no parens
```